# Show Stripe modal on same page instead of show modal in "https://checkout.stripe.com/v3/..."

Tags: php, jquery, laravel, stripe-payments

I have a form for a user do a payment using Stripe and the jQuery below.

But when the user clicks in the "Pay" buton instead of the Stripe modal opens on the page the user is redirected to "https://checkout.stripe.com/v3/....html?distinct_id=..." and the Stripe modal appears on that page.

Do you know why the Stripe modal is not appearing in the current page?

```
 <form action="{{ route('payment.chargeStripe') }}" method="post" id="paymentForm">
    {{csrf_field()}}
    <div id="credit_card_section">  
        <div class="alert alert-info" role="alert">
            <strong><i class="fa fa-info" aria-hidden="true"></i></strong>
            Click in "Pay" to pay.
        </div>
        <input type="hidden" name="stripeToken" id="stripeToken"/>
        <input type="submit" href="" id="payment" class="btn btn-primary" value=" Pay"/>
    </div>
</form>
```

jQuery:

```
<script src="https://js.stripe.com/v3/"></script>
<script src="https://checkout.stripe.com/checkout.js"></script>


<script>
$(function () {
    let stripe = StripeCheckout.configure({
        key: "{{config('services.stripe.key')}}",
        image: "",
        locale: "auto",
        token: (token) => {
            document.querySelector('#stripeToken').value = token.id;
            document.querySelector('#paymentForm').submit();
        }
    });

    document.getElementById('payment').addEventListener('click', function(e){

        stripe.open({
            name: 'test',
            description: '{{session('conference_name')}}',
            amount: '{{session('total') * 100}}',
            currency: 'eur'

        });
        e.preventDefault();
    });

    // Close Checkout on page navigation:
    window.addEventListener('popstate', function() {
        handler.close();
    });
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$(function () {
    let stripe = StripeCheckout.configure({
        key: "{{YOUR_STRIPE_PUBLIC_KEY}}",
        image: "",
        locale: "auto",
        token: (token) => {
            document.querySelector('#stripeToken').value = token.id;
            document.querySelector('#paymentForm').submit();
        }
    });
    document.getElementById('payment').addEventListener('click', function(e){
        stripe.open({
            name: 'test',
            description: '{{YOUR_DESCRIPTION}}',
            amount: '12',
            currency: 'eur'
        });
        e.preventDefault();
    });

    // Close Checkout on page navigation:
    window.addEventListener('popstate', function() {
        handler.close();
    });
});
```

From the code you have posted, it seems it working fine, but its missing function closing parentheses and a bracket. See last line of my code. Once i fixed this one i can able to see the checkout popup in my current page itself.

Also check in browser console, to make sure there is not js error.

Comment: Thanks, I have that "});" but I didnt post the full js because there is other js not related to Stripe. On the console only appears "StripeCheckout.open: Type mismatch for option 'amount':
Looking for type 'number', but instead we found 'string'.
You can learn about the available configuration options in the Checkout docs:".

Comment: Hmm it sounds like you have given a string value for amount field. You need to convert the values to integer before you assign. Also make sure you are not giving any decimal values. say values like "10.25" are considered as invalid. Please do console of your total value and see what you assign there., if its a string then convert it into integer with parseInt()

Comment: Thanks, changing the amount to static 2500 like " amount: '2500',
" works.  I get the total with "$total = Session::get('total');" and it shows "12.3". Do you know to properly have a correct total?

Comment: If your Session::get('total') return 12.3 then by your code (12.3 *100) should return 1230 right ?? Can you please check once what you get as output when you multiply your total with 100 ? you can do it simply like this before your stripe.open() function. var newTotal = {{session('total') * 100}}; console.log(newTotal);

Comment: it sounds weird, can you able to get correct value  with this code in Session::get('total') ??  `var newTotal = {{ Session::get('total') }} * 100;
        stripe.open({
            name: 'test',
            description: 'sfgsdfgsdfgsdg',
            amount: newTotal,
            currency: 'eur'
        });`

if so try assiging value like above

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/174595/discussion-between-ashok-and-john).